# JAVA MVC - passing username to another servlet

Tags: java, model-view-controller

currently i am working on a booking website, after the user login, the username will be automatically catch and shows on everypage with the code below:

```
<%
        HttpSession sessionUser = request.getSession(false);
        String s = (String)sessionUser.getAttribute("username");
        traveller t = new traveller();
        t.setUsername(s);
        t.getUsername();

        out.print("Hello ");
        out.print(t.getUsername());

    %>
```

my question is because i need to pass other information user input information to servlet along with username as the primary key to identify the booked user so my question is how can I pass the username in this page to the servlet and finally to the model and insert into database

Comment: You stored the `username` in `session`. so you can use `session` object to get `username` in `servlet` again.

Comment: The session is the way to go. That said, please don't use raw servlets for controller, and don't use scriptlets in your JSP. You are in for a hell of a time if you go that way. Pick a nice web framework such as SpringMVC (there are many others to choose from), it will make your life better ! And follow Java code conventions : class names are PascalCase !

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `traveller` object inside http session and each time you need traveller or username you just retrieve it inside your session.

first thing you have to do is inserting your object to session.

```
sessionUser.setAttribute("traveller definition key",t);
```

then you can retrieve your parameter whenever you want via session.

```
traveller t = (traveller)sessionUser.getAttribute("traveller definition key");
```

i have used `traveller` instance in example but it is same for `String`.
don't carry your login information via form or http parameter, i can easily change the parameter carried via form and became another user. HttpSession is much safer way.

Answer (score 0):

Can set username as value of a hidden field of the form...
So when user submit the form, username will be sent too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to share this user info trough all your layers is the [Context Object pattern](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/Context-Object-Pattern.pdf). It'll allow you to

> pass other information user input information to servlet along with username as the primary key to identify the booked user so my question is how can I pass the username in this page to the servlet and finally to the model and insert into database

Be sure to implement it correctly and that the data intended for `application/session/request/other` scope is not put directly into `ServletContext/HttpSession/HttpRequest/other` protocol-specific class. Instead, the data is stored in a POJO wrapper class, that then sits in the `ServletRequest/HttpSession/HttpRequest/other`.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is already correct except that you overlooked. You need to pass the user object instead of the userName.

```
    HttpSession loginSession = request.getSession(false);//reference name modified
    User user = (User)loginSession.getAttribute(userObj);
```

The setAttribute(Object obj) signatures helps you to store any object is session and not just String.

If you are using a web framework like Spring/Struts, use JSTL or Expressions to get the session.